# How can I make the scanner of a Canon E500 work?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, canon, scanner

10 years ago I thought I made a BIG mistake when I bought my Laser LBP800. Getting it to work with Ubuntu was disastrous.

Now, 10 years later, I thought things had improved. So I got this Canon E500 (scanner + printer).

But I was wrong! It's still disaster! I got the printing going with a download from here: http://support-in.canon-asia.com/contents/IN/EN/0100396801.html

However, I cannot get the scanner to work. I have no clue on how this should be done.

Is there anyone who has successfully got the whole thing running?

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

You should try this : http://support-my.canon-asia.com/contents/MY/EN/0100397001.html

Comment: I haven't even tried it. Thanks for your answer. But can someone honestly tell me why this answer is down-voted?

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't get the scanner working. I run the deb files (32 bit) and also the install.sh script but the scanner is not even detected. Not listed. Anyway, thanks for your time.